# Instagram Browser ( from App On IOS) doesn't display the menu of my website

Tags: ios, instagram, shopify

We are having a really strange problem with Instagram on IOS. 
When we try to open the link of our website https://www.eloisebeauty.com/ (Shopify) the menu disappears. 
We tested the website across all Browser, so I can't really understand where is the problem.... and for us is extremely important that our customers are able to open the website properly

Any suggestion?